# Python: Trouble adding spaces to elements in row based on max length in column

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, tabs, spaces

I am writing a script that adds spaces to items in a column and calculates those spaces by subtracting the length of the item from the maximum length of all of the items in a column.

I threw together some test data, which is a 2-Dimensional list.

I have been working on this for days now and have made progress. Now, I am running into issues with adding way too many spaces to each item.

My idea is to create an array of the lengths of each item, a list of the max lengths in each column, and an array of the spaces needed, then add the value in the array of spaces needed to the item, except for the item with the maximum length in the column.

I cannot use `numpy` or `pandas`, so I have been forced to build a tabulation utility, using built-ins only.

Please help me see where this is going wrong, and let me know if there is a more efficient and simple way to accomplish this.

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
from array import array

a_list = [['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7'],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 1, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 13, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(1998, 7, 20, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 31, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 12, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 3, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 16, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 17, 0, 0)],
['Blah', '0316497313', None, '13', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(1998, 4, 17, 0, 0)],]

columns = a_list[0]
# print(columns)
#print(a_list[:][0])

rows = a_list[1:]
#print(rows)

column_count = len(a_list[:][0])
# print(column_count)
space = r' '
tab = space*4

# Note 'H' is signed short int
lengths = [array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', [])]
max_length = array('H', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
max_values = []
spaces_needed = [array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', []), array('H', [])]

print('\na_list before:\n{}\n'.format([row for row in a_list]))

# setup columns based on column_count
count = 1
for col in range(column_count):
    indexer = 0
    for row in a_list:
        try:
            lengths[col].append(len(row[col]))
        except TypeError as type_error:
            #print(type_error)
            # if cannot get len() of NoneType, use length
            # of column name less 1
            lengths[col].append(len(columns[col])-1)
        indexer += 1

    # get max string length in columns
    max_length[col] = max(lengths[col])
    # print('max_length: {}'.format(max_length))

    # calculate spaces needed and append to spaces_needed list
    indexer = 0
    for item in lengths[col]:
        spaces_needed[col].append(abs(max_length[col] - item))
        indexer += 1

    print('lengths Column {}\t{}'.format(count, lengths[col]))
    count += 1

count = 1
for col in range(column_count):
    indexer = 0
    for row in a_list:
        # print('iteration: {}\tRow: {}'.format(indexer, row))

        sub_indexer = 0
        for i in row:

            loc = row.index(i)
            i = str(i)

            # get max length values and add to its own list
            if len(i) in max_length:
                #=print('{} {} {}'.format(i, len(i), True))
                max_values.append(i)
                i += tab
                row[loc] = i
                sub_indexer += 1
                continue

            #print('{} {}'.format(i, type(i)))
            i += space * spaces_needed[col][indexer] + tab
            row[loc] = i
            sub_indexer += 1

        indexer += 1

    count += 1

# remove duplicates in list
max_values = list(set(max_values))
print('\nmax_values:\t{}\n'.format(max_values))
print('spaces_needed:\n{}'.format(spaces_needed))

print('\na_list after:\n{}\n'.format([row for row in a_list]))
```

Here is the output I made to help you see what is going on:

```
a_list before:
[['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7'], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 1, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 13, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(1998, 7, 20, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 31, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 12, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 3, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 16, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '14', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 17, 0, 0)], ['Blah', '0316497313', None, '13', None, datetime.timedelta(16495, 49560), datetime.datetime(1998, 4, 17, 0, 0)]]

lengths Column 1    array('H', [7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
lengths Column 2    array('H', [7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
lengths Column 3    array('H', [7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6])
lengths Column 4    array('H', [7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
lengths Column 5    array('H', [7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6])
lengths Column 6    array('H', [7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6])
lengths Column 7    array('H', [7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6])

max_values: ['column2', 'column6', 'column7', 'column1', 'column3', 'column5', 'column4', '0316497313']

spaces_needed:
[array('H', [0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]), array('H', [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array('H', [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array('H', [0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]), array('H', [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array('H', [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array('H', [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])]

a_list after:
[['column1                               ', 'column2                               ', 'column3                               ', 'column4                               ', 'column5                               ', 'column6                               ', 'column7                               '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '2010-02-01 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '2016-06-13 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '2015-06-23 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '1998-07-20 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '2019-07-31 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '2016-09-12 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '2015-05-03 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '1998-02-16 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '2017-06-23 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '14                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '2010-07-17 00:00:00                                        '], ['Blah                                        ', '0316497313                                     ', 'None                                        ', '13                                        ', 'None                                        ', '16495 days, 13:46:00                                        ', '1998-04-17 00:00:00                                        ']]
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = iter(a_list)
next(rows) # remove this line if you want to include headers

max_widths = [max(map(len, map(str, col)))  for  col in zip(*rows)]
# [4, 10, 4, 2, 4, 20, 19]

column_sep = '  ' # two spaces
fmt = column_sep.join('{{!s:{}}}'.format(w) for w in max_widths)
# '{!s:4}  {!s:10}  {!s:4}  {!s:2}  {!s:4}  {!s:20}  {!s:19}'

rows = iter(a_list)
next(rows)  # remove this line if you want to include headers

for row in rows:
    print(fmt.format(*row))
```

Comment: Would you please help me understand `fmt = column_sep.join('{{!s:{}}}'.format(w) for w in max_widths)`? It works, just want to understand this better.

Comment: @Debug255:  Sure.  First let's look at one of the format strings we're creating: `'{!s:10}'`.  If we do `{!s:10}.format(None)` the curly brackets indicate that a string gets formatted there.   `!s` means format as string.  The `:10` means left justify in a 10 character wide field.  Now in `'{{!s:{}}}'.format(w)` I'm creating format strings like `'{!s:10}'`.  In order to get curly brackets in my output I have to double them so that `.format()` ignores them.  All this is wrapped in a generator expression that iterates over `max_widths` so we get a format string for each width.